# Python Recursion Exercise

Tags: python

I am doing exercise on Singpath and I am stuck at this question. This question is under recursion exercises but I have no idea what the question means.

> A number, `a`, is a power of `b` if it is
>   divisible by `b` and `a/b` is a power of
>   `b`.
>   Write a function called `is_power`
>   that takes parameters `a` and `b` and
>   returns `True` if `a` is a power of `b`.

**Update:**

Just thought of the answer and I've posted it below.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429044/check-if-one-integer-is-an-integer-power-of-another

Comment: Is this homework?  power a == b**x;

Comment: @kevpie: The question is whether an integer x exist.

Comment: @adam-matan, yes. My cryptic message was supposed to help show that.  Not so much I guess.

Comment: yes, it's homework and it's from Singpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer...

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if(a%b != 0):
        return False
    elif(a/b == 1):
        return True
    else:
        return is_power(a/b,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a recursive definition of power. You are supposed to write the function

```
def is_power(a, b):
  ...
```

The definition give a general property. hint for the terminal case. if a and b are equals the function should answer true.

Comment: yup..my answer is giving me "All the public tests passed but some private tests failed. You need to generalize your solution."

Answer (score 1):

Think about what it will do, at present, if you give it, say a=32 and b=2. `b*b` will give you 4, 16, 256...

So, you have to keep track of the original `b` as you're calling your function recursively. You could have a third variable with a default value (`original_b`), but there's a way to do it without replacing `b` at all.

Comment: yup...that's why my answer is not fully corrected although it fulfilled the given situations. may I know how to correct it?

Comment: @MyatNoe: I've updated my post. I'm trying not to just tell you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look more closely at the information you are given:

> A number, a, is a power of b if it is divisible by b and a/b is a power of b.

It says "... and a/b is a power of b". It does not say "... and a is a power of b*b". There is a reason for that: you don't get the same results with the two different definitions.

Now look at your code for the recursive call:

```
return is_power(a,b*b)
```

We don't care if a is a power of b*b; we care if a/b is a power of b. So why are we calling `is_power(a, b*b) # is a a power of b*b?` ? Instead, we should call... well, I think you can figure it out :)

Why it's different: let's say the recursion happens twice. When we start out calling the function, let's say b = 2. On the first recursion, we pass 2 * 2 = 4. On the next recursion, the input was 4, so we pass 4 * 4 = 16. But we skipped the check for 2 * 2 * 2 = 8. 8 is a power of 2, but if we call `is_power(8, 2)`, then `is_power(8,8)` never happens, and then `is_power(8, 16)` returns False.

Answer (score 1):

```
def isp(a,b):  
    if a%b==0 and isp(a/b,b):
        return True
    elif a/b==b:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the trivial cases, there are two in fact: `is_power(x,x)` and `is_power(1,x)`.

Once you have the edge case you just need to write down the definition correctly. It mentions `a/b` and `b`, but you wrote `return is_power(a,b*b)`. Maybe you think that is the same, just scaled both arguments with b, but it is not. Think about the values of `b` in `is_power(27,3)`.

Comment: One edge case is enough: `is_power(1, x)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def power(a,b):
if a<=b:
    if a==b: return True
    else:return False
elif a%b==0: return power(a/b,b)
else: return
```

Comment: Would you consider explaining this a bit, and why/how it is an answer to the question which was asked above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the edge case where a = 0 (which some of the answers above do). I just wanted to point in out in particular, because it's easy to see why a = 1 is an important edge case, but a = 0 is also important because if you don't acknowledge it in some way you may end up with infinite recursion.

If it helps, this is how I approached it:

```
def is_power(a, b):
    if a == b or a == 1:
        # a == b is the 'success' base case (a is a power of b)
        # a == 1 is the success edge case where a is 1 (b ^ 0)
        return True
    elif a % b != 0 or a == 0:
        # a % b != 0 is the 'failure' base case (a is not a power of b)
        # a == 0 is the failure edge case where a is 0. If
        # you don't acknowledge this case in some way, the function
        # will recurse forever
        return False
    else:
        # else, keep recursing
        return is_power(a / b, b)


print is_power(8, 2) # True
print is_power(6, 2) # False
print is_power(0, 2) # False
print is_power(1, 2) # True
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_power(a, b):
    if a%b == 0 and a/b**b:
        return True
    else:
        return False

is_power(10, 12)
```