# Checking if an integer is an integer power of another?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

This is identical to the question found on [Check if one integer is an integer power of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429044/check-if-one-integer-is-an-integer-power-of-another), but I am wondering about the complexity of a method that I came up with to solve this problem.

Given an integer `n` and another integer `m`, is `n = m^p` for some integer `p`. Note that `^` here is exponentiation and not `xor`.

There is a simple O(log_m n) solution based on dividing `n` repeatedly by `m` until it's 1 or until there's a non-zero remainder.

I'm thinking of a method inspired by binary search, and it's not clear to me how complexity should be calculated in this case.

Essentially you start with `m`, then you go to `m^2`, then `m^4`, `m^8`, `m^16`, .....
When you find that `m^{2^k} > n`, you check the range bounded by `m^{2^{k-1}}` and `m^{2^k}`. Is this solution `O(log_2 (log_m(n)))`?

Somewhat related to this, if I do something like

```
m^2 * m^2
```

vs.

```
m * m * m * m
```

Do these 2 have the same complexity? If they do, then I think the algorithm I came up with is still `O(log_m (n))`

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the complexity of your algorithm is `log_2 (log_m (n))`. Also note that `log_m(n) = log_2(n) / log_2(m)`; thus `log_2 (log_m (n)) = log_2(log_2(n)) - log_2(log_2(m))`.

Comment: You can use math formula: `p = log(n) / log(m)`; if `p` is close to some round int, you can try to verify result, by compute power `m^p` with quick power function, works as `log(p)`.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. First of all, let's assume that multiplication is `O(1)`, and exponentiation `a^b` is `O(log b)` (using exponentiation by squaring).

Now using your method of doubling the exponent `p_candidate` and then doing a binary search, you can find the real `p` in `log(p)` steps (or observe that `p` does not exist). But each try within the binary search requires you to compute `m^p_candidate`, which is bounded by `m^p`, which by assumption is `O(log(p))`. So the overall time complexity is `O(log^2(p))`.

But we want to express the time complexity in terms of the inputs `n` and `m`. From the relationship `n = m^p`, we get `p = log(n)/log(m)`, and hence `log(p) = log(log(n)/log(m))`. Hence the overall time complexity is

```
O(log^2(log(n)/log(m)))
```

If you want to get rid of the `m`, you can provide a looser upper bound by using

```
O(log^2(log(n)))
```

which is close to, but not quite `O(log(log(n)))`.
(Note that you can always omit the logarithmic bases in the O-notation since all logarithmic functions differ only by a constant factor.)

Now, the interesting question is: is this algorithm better than one that is `O(log(n))`? I haven't proved it, but I'm pretty certain it is the case that `O(log^2(log(n)))` is in `O(log(n))` but not vice versa. Anyone cares to prove it?

Comment: Oops yeah I realized that after posting and forgot to edit the question. Do you agree that finding the bounds is O(log(log n))? Also I put the bases for the logs here because it helps visualize the case

Comment: You mean finding the upper bound for `p`? Yes, since each squaring (e.g. getting from `m^8` to `m^16`) is assumed to be `O(1)`, you only need `log(p)` tries, which is `log(log(n)/log(m))` which in turn is bounded by `log(log(n))`.

Comment: Yes. But the thing idk if it's correct for us to make that assumption of `O(1)`. This is one of the things about complexity analysis that confuses me in that when can we assume some standard mathematical operation can be performed in constant time.

Comment: These assumptions are always simplifications. It is a valid assumption if your integers fit into the word size of the CPU, so multiplication can be done in a bounded and small number of CPU cycles. If your integers are unbounded, the assumption is not valid anymore.